# What's the best method to get the input function parameter into a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what I want is, for a function:

```
def test(a = 1, b = 2):
    return {'a':a, 'b':b}
```

for example test(a=2,b=1) gives {'a':2,'b':1}. I want to do this automatically (like packing all the parameter into a dictionay), because my function is under development and there will be a lot of more arguments added, so I don't want to add this everywhere, is there a clean way to do so?

**The function's form must be test(a=1,b=2), I can't change this into test(**kwarg), because it will be a huge change to the existing code. I am asking is there a way to get the dict from the form of input like (a=1,b=2)**

Comment: check **kwargs.

Comment: @taurus05, not really what I need, in fact I need the reverse. I can't do test(**kwarg) right now, I need to pack all the argument into dict.

Comment: @RushengZhang I can't imagine a world where there's a smaller change than `test(a=1, b=2) -> test(**kwargs)`.

Comment: Why does changing this function definition affect the rest of the code? Or just `test = dict`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. It almost sounds like you just want `dict(a=1, b=2)`

Comment: @Adam Smith because now the function has like 30 parameters and by doing so I need to change every places from self.a=a to self.a=kwargs.a, something like this...

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'm also very confused, can you not show more code to illustrate your issue.

Comment: @RushengZhang is this a method in a *class*? Why didn't you mention that?

Comment: @Adam Smith Yes, for my use case, it's a class method, but I just thought it's irrelevant because even it's just a function, will have the same issue maintaining a quite big function and get all the input list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def test(a = 1, b= 2):
    x =  locals()
    print(x)
test(a=5, b=6)
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I want

Comment: note: `locals` will have all local variables not just the arguments, which may not be an issue in this case.

Comment: There are only 2 local variables inside this function. So, there won't be any issue, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use kwargs

```
def test(**kwargs):
   return kwargs
print (test(a=1,b=2))  
#OUTPUT:{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```